# JS:Select and move a specific div to front

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple card stack which rotates when clicked, my problem is I cant select a specific card and send it to the front and arrange again the cards according to number. I change the codes but luck, I consumed half a day to make it works, still not working.

I hope you understand me.

Thanks

here is a sample code.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gerryl1991/pen/YeyyXK)

```js
var cardStack = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var cardArray = []; // Does not change
var stateArray = []; // Changes - keeps track of card state
var prevStateArray = [];

function cardInit() {
  for (var i=0; i<cardStack.length; i++) {
    var cNum = i + 1;
    var cName = 'card' + cNum.toString();
    cardStack[i].classList.add(cName);
    cardArray.push(cNum);
    stateArray = cardArray;
  };
  
};

function stackRefresh() {
  
  prevStateArray = stateArray.slice(0);
  stateArray.unshift(stateArray.pop());
  
}

function nextCard() {
  
  stackRefresh();
  
  for (var i=0; i<cardStack.length; i++) {
    var cName = 'card' + prevStateArray[i].toString();
    var cNameNew = 'card' + stateArray[i].toString();
    cardStack[i].classList.remove(cName);
    cardStack[i].classList.add(cNameNew);
  };
  
}

cardInit();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.card-stack {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.card1 {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
}

.card2 {
  z-index: 800;
  transform: scale(0.99);
  filter: brightness(0.9);
  left: 20px;
}

.card3 {
  z-index: 600;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  left: 40px;
}

.card4 {
  z-index: 400;
  transform: scale(0.97);
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  left: 60px;
  animation-name: remove;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes remove {
  0% {transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1};
  50% {transform: translateX(-80px); opacity: 0};
  51% {transform: translateX(10px) scale(0.97); opacity: 0};
  100% {transform: translateX(0px) scale(0.97); opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="card-stack" onclick="nextCard();">
  <div class="card">A</div>
  <div class="card">B</div>
  <div class="card">C</div>
  <div class="card">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I use javascript framework (e.g. jquery)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NyGNxW)

I changed html

```
<div class="card-stack" onclick="nextCard(event);">
...
```

And js function

```
function nextCard(e) {
  var clickedCssClass = e.srcElement.classList[1];
  if (!clickedCssClass) return;
  var match = /(\d+)/.exec(clickedCssClass);
  var clickedNumber = match[0];

  for(var j = 1; j < clickedNumber ; j++){
    stackRefresh();
    for (var i=0; i<cardStack.length; i++) {
      var cName = 'card' + prevStateArray[i].toString();
      var cNameNew = 'card' + stateArray[i].toString();
      cardStack[i].classList.remove(cName);
      cardStack[i].classList.add(cNameNew);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you sir it works, can I ask last request, can you disabled the transition if you click the top card..

Answer (score 1):

First include the following statement in head section of the html:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
```

Add then change the following tag

```
 <div class="card-stack" onclick="nextCard();">
```

To

```
  <div class="card-stack">
```

Finally, I modified the function cardInit as follow:

```
        function cardInit() {
          for (var i=0; i<cardStack.length; i++) {
            var cNum = i + 1;
            var cName = 'card' + cNum.toString();
            cardStack[i].classList.add(cName);
            $(cardStack[i]).on("click",function()
                                {
                                    prevClassName=this.classList[1];
                                    $(".card1").removeClass("card1").addClass(prevClassName);
                                    this.className=this.className.replace(prevClassName,"card1");
                                });                         
            cardArray.push(cNum);
            stateArray = cardArray;
          };

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

did you mean this?

I have added a `moveTop` function like

```
function moveTop() {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.card')).indexOf(event.target)
  var temp = stateArray[index];
  prevStateArray = stateArray.slice(0);
  stateArray.splice(index, 1);
  stateArray.unshift(temp);

  refreshCards();

}
```

```js
var cardStack = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
var cardArray = []; // Does not change
var stateArray = []; // Changes - keeps track of card state
var prevStateArray = [];

function cardInit() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cardStack.length; i++) {
    var cNum = i + 1;
    var cName = 'card' + cNum.toString();
    cardStack[i].classList.add(cName);
    cardArray.push(cNum);
    stateArray = cardArray;
  };

};

function stackRefresh() {
  prevStateArray = stateArray.slice(0);
  stateArray.unshift(stateArray.pop());
}

function nextCard() {
  stackRefresh();
  refreshCards();
}

function refreshCards() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cardStack.length; i++) {
    var cName = 'card' + prevStateArray[i].toString();
    var cNameNew = 'card' + stateArray[i].toString();
    cardStack[i].classList.remove(cName);
    cardStack[i].classList.add(cNameNew);
  };
}

function moveTop() {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var index = Array.prototype.slice.call(event.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.card')).indexOf(event.target)
  var temp = stateArray[index];
  prevStateArray = stateArray.slice(0);
  stateArray.splice(index, 1);
  stateArray.unshift(temp);

  refreshCards();

}
cardInit();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  text-align: right;
}

.card-stack {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.card1 {
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
}

.card2 {
  z-index: 800;
  transform: scale(0.99);
  filter: brightness(0.9);
  left: 20px;
}

.card3 {
  z-index: 600;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  filter: brightness(0.8);
  left: 40px;
}

.card4 {
  z-index: 400;
  transform: scale(0.97);
  filter: brightness(0.7);
  left: 60px;
  animation-name: remove;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes remove {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
    opacity: 1
  }
  ;
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-80px);
    opacity: 0
  }
  ;
  51% {
    transform: translateX(10px) scale(0.97);
    opacity: 0
  }
  ;
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0px) scale(0.97);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card-stack" onclick="nextCard();">
  <div class="card" onclick="moveTop()">A</div>
  <div class="card" onclick="moveTop()">B</div>
  <div class="card" onclick="moveTop()">C</div>
  <div class="card" onclick="moveTop()">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it work sir if you clicked them according to letters but on random, nope.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you don't know which card was clicked. My guess is to pass the event when calling nextCard():

```
onclick="nextCard(event)"
```

And within the function:

```
function nextCard(event) {
 // detect which card was picked 
 console.log(event.target);
 // logic to bring picked card to the top
 ...
}
```